# Xamarin Binding a Grid to a ViewCell in a ListView

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I dynamically (has to be dynamic) build a Grid in code and want the Grid to be the only thing in a ListView.  The code to create the Grid works fine (tested), but now I want to put the Grid inside a ListView, so that I can make use of the ListView's "Pull Down Refresh" functionality.

My code looks like this:

```
// ... Build the Grid

// Set the item source of the ListView to this one Grid
MatrixCells.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<Grid>(new List<Grid> { grid });
```

My Xaml looks like this:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="MatrixCells"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding ReloadProjectCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsLoading, Mode=OneWay}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <!-- WHAT GOES HERE ?? -->
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My question is how do I bind the whole of the item in the ListView to the Grid I have created?  See the "WHAT GOES HERE ??".

I have tried:

```
<Grid BindingContext="{Binding}" />
```

Which I know does not make sense... And a few other things, but cannot get the Grid to show.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now working.  My Xaml looks like this:

```
<ListView
    x:Name="MatrixCells"
    HasUnevenRows="True"
    IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
    RefreshCommand="{Binding ReloadProjectCommand}"
    IsRefreshing="{Binding IsLoading, Mode=OneWay}">

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

and the relevant code looks like this:

```
        var matrix = GetMatrix();

        MatrixCells.ItemsSource = new List<Grid> { matrix };
        MatrixCells.ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(() => new ViewCell { View = matrix, Height = MatrixCells.Height });
```

The **HasUnevenRows="True"** and the setting the Height to the same height as the ListView in new ViewCell { View = matrix, **Height = MatrixCells.Height** }   were **very** important.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an observable collection of `Grid`, In your `ViewCell` add the list of grids to the ViewCells View property something like below, make sure you have **HasUnevenRows="True"**  in your ListView properties:

```
 <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell View="{Binding .}"/>                       
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

### EDIT

I just checked and it seems that View is not a bindable property, sorry for the inconvenience...

What you can do is create the DataTemplate from the C# side and assign it to the ListView something like this:

```
public class WithDataTemplatePageCS : ContentPage
{
public WithDataTemplatePageCS()
{
    ...
    var people = new List<Person>
    {
        new Person { Name = "Steve", Age = 21, Location = "USA" },
        ...
    };

    var personDataTemplate = new DataTemplate(() =>
    {
        var grid = new Grid();
        ...
        var nameLabel = new Label { FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold };
        var ageLabel = new Label();
        var locationLabel = new Label { HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.End };

        nameLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Name");
        ageLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Age");
        locationLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Location");

        grid.Children.Add(nameLabel);
        grid.Children.Add(ageLabel, 1, 0);
        grid.Children.Add(locationLabel, 2, 0);

        return new ViewCell { View = grid };
    });

    Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Margin = new Thickness(20),
        Children = {
            ...
            new ListView { ItemsSource = people, ItemTemplate = personDataTemplate, Margin = new Thickness(0, 20, 0, 0) }
        }
    };
}
}
```

For more information on this, you check the [Micorsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/templates/data-templates/creating)

Comment: That gives the following error on compilation:
No property, bindable property, or event found for 'View', or mismatching type between value and property.

Comment: I have got the Grid to appear, using the technique above, except it is very small.  I need to increase the height of THE single list item (the Grid) to fill the whole of the page.

Comment: You want a single item the size of a page?

Comment: Yes, I want a single item the size of a page.  The ListView does fill the page, it's the item that does not.  Originally my Grid did fill the page.  But since I added it to a ListView, it has become very small.

Comment: Well that is how it works, ListView items are not meant to be the size of the page, It would be better if you just have it fill the required size

Comment: Thank yo for your help.  I just set HasUnevenRows=true and now the Grid displays too big!!!  But I should be able to work it out from now.

Comment: Sure, mark this as an answer if it worked for you!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way for refresh content, You can use [PullToRefresh](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh/) package.
Wrap your grid with scrollview, define your command and use like this

```
xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh;assembly=Refractored.XamForms.PullToRefresh"

<controls:PullToRefreshLayout
      IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"
      RefreshCommand="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
      IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}"
      RefreshColor="Blue">
    <ScrollView
      HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
      VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <Grid>....</Grid>
    </ScrollView>
</controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
```

you can also check this [github](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/Xamarin.Forms-PullToRefreshLayout)